# Can readers display books "by the page"

Tags: ebook-readers, file-format

Most readers I've encountered show their book contents as text, ie. as a continuous stream, instead of the "page view" you find in physical books or PDF. the "next page" button brings you not to "one page ahead" but instead to "one page worth of text ahead".

What would it take to have it display immutable pages with original (or fixed) page layout? Is it a matter of reader's brand? Configuration? A property of the file (like PDF vs epub)?

Comment: Because ereaders come in many sizes and have differing resolutions, it is best to let the device optimize the view, displaying as many characters per line as are readable. The *raison d'être* for PDF, *Page Description Format*, is to create an immutable document of fixed size. For that reason, I find PDF much harder to read on ereaders, though it is effective for publishing a paper document or résumé.